# Integrating Different Modules into One android application

Tags: android, integration

i broke up my android project into multiple modules. These modules include pdf viewer, ocr application and XMPP application. Now i have these 3 modules in the form of 3 different applications. How can i integrate these 3 applications so that i be having a single running application. baiscally i want to merge those 3 applications into 1. Ofcourse rewriting code into one project would be difficult. Could anybody suggest me how can i accomplish this?? all the possiblities please. I was thinking to these 3 android projects as library projects and use them as a dependency for 4th project but i dnt know how this actually works!

Answer (score 1):

Add those 3 projects as Library in your fourth project!

If you dont know how to set a project as library, [Set as Libray project (Vogella.com)](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html#tutorial_library_flag)
and [Use library project (Vogella.com)](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html#tutorial_library_usage) can be really helpful for you!

Comment: would my problem be solved. i mean how does this work?? would  i be able to call the functions from the library project ?? how??